# Call interface method from service

Tags: android, service

I try to implement interface from service (guess, it's not a good practice), but interface method is not called in it.

```
class TrackerService : Service(), LocationUpdateListener {

override fun onCreate() {
    startLocationTracking(context) // context as this service with LocationUpdateListener, next it should trigger onLocationUpdated after some time
}

override fun onLocationUpdated(location: Location?) {
    // Not called
}

// ... Service lifecycle methods
}
```

How to interact back to service, when I do some actions on it's onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

You might have some confusion with how to use the interface. An interface is a way of abstracting methods to different classes. If your service is meant to call methods in an interface, you likely want some other class to implement it. You'd then give a reference of that class to your service, and when an action is finished, the service will call your object name, then the method name.

Implementing the interface directly in your service means that your service guarantees these methods when other classes use it.

Check to see if the first case is what you wish to achieve.

Edit: If you're calling a method that requires an interface for a callback, then make sure you pass `this`. And if you are making your own interface, make sure the method is actually called somewhere, as it doesn't seem to be the case in your example